# Задержать выполнения функции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть написанный мной код, который работает, но не выполняет правильно одну функцию. Помогите разобраться, почему.

Код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var timer = null;
    $('#searchword').keydown(function(e){

        if( e.keyCode ==38 ){
            if( $('#search_suggestion_holder').is(':visible') ){
                if( ! $('.selected').is(':visible') ){
                    $('#search_suggestion_holder li').last().addClass('selected');
                }else{
                    var i =  $('#search_suggestion_holder li').index($('#search_suggestion_holder li.selected')) ;
                    $('#search_suggestion_holder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    i--;
                    $('#search_suggestion_holder li:eq('+i+')').addClass('selected');

                }
            }
        }else if(e.keyCode ==40){
            if( $('#search_suggestion_holder').is(':visible') ){
                if( ! $('.selected').is(':visible') ){
                    $('#search_suggestion_holder li').first().addClass('selected');
                }else{
                    var i =  $('#search_suggestion_holder li').index($('#search_suggestion_holder li.selected')) ;
                    $('#search_suggestion_holder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    i++;
                    $('#search_suggestion_holder li:eq('+i+')').addClass('selected');
                }
            }
        }else if(e.keyCode ==13){
            if( $('.selected').is(':visible') ){
                var value   =   $('.selected').text();
                $('#searchword').val(value);
                $('#search_suggestion_holder').hide();
                $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
                $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
                sendsearch()
            }
        }
        });




    $('#searchword').bind('textchange', function (event, numberkey) {
        var keyword = $(this).val()
        //console.log("это:" + keyword) 

        if(keyword.length > 3)
                {
                $('#loader').show();
                setTimeout( function(){
                    var d = []
                    $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
                    $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'auto-complete.php',
                        data:'keyword='+keyword,
                        dataType:'json',
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('ошибка, F12');
                            console.log('jqXHR:');
                            console.log(jqXHR);
                            console.log('статус:');
                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log('ошибка:');
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        },

                        success: function(d){
                        //console.log($.isEmptyObject(d));
                        if (!! $.isEmptyObject(d)){
                            //console.log("1")
                            var nafin = '<li class="hover-img">Нечего не найдено</li>'
                            $("#search_suggestion_holder").html(nafin)
                            $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
                            $('#loader').hide();
                        }
                        else {
                        //console.log("2")

                        $.each(d, function(i, val) {
                            //console.log(val.icon + val.value);
                            //console.log(i);
                            var descrmin = val.descr.substr(0, 150);
                            //console.log(descrmin)
                            var hoverimg = "img-hover=\"<img src=/shop/medium/" + val.icon+"> <br> "+ descrmin + "\""
                            var resultat = '<li class="hover-img" title ' + hoverimg + '><img src="/shop/32x32/' + val.icon + '">' + val.value + '</li>'
                            //console.log(resultat)
                            $('#loader').hide();
                            $(resultat).appendTo("#search_suggestion_holder")
                            //console.log($("#search_suggestion_holder").html());
                            $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
                            $(".hover-img").tooltip({
                                content: function (event, ui) {
                                        return $(this).attr('img-hover');
                                        },
                                        track: true,
                                    });
                            })
                        }
                        }           
                    });
                },1500);
            }
        else if(keyword.length < 1){
                $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
                $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
                $('#search_suggestion_holder').hide();
                var newwrite = '<li class="hover-img">начните вводить</li>'
                //console.log(newwrite)
                $("#search_suggestion_holder").html(newwrite)
                $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
                $('#loader').hide();
                }
        else if(1 > keyword.length < 3){

                $('#loader').show();
                $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
                $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
                $('#search_suggestion_holder').hide();
                var min3 = '<li class="hover-img">Введите больше 3 символов</li>'
                //console.log(min3)
                $("#search_suggestion_holder").html(min3)
                $('#search_suggestion_holder').show();
                $('#loader').hide();
                //console.log($("#search_suggestion_holder").html());
            }   
        })


        $('#search_suggestion_holder').on('click','li',function(){
        var value   =   $(this).text();
        $('#searchword').val(value);
        $('#search_suggestion_holder').hide();
        $('#search_suggestion_holder li').detach();
        $('div.ui-tooltip').detach();
        sendsearch()
        })

        function sendsearch() {
        $("#searchnow").click();
        }
});
```

В нем есть `setTimeout( function(){`, которая по логике оборачивает всю функцию запроса к PHP-скрипту и замедляет её выполнение на `1500 мс`. Логика такова, что если человек быстро печатает, её не вызвать, а на деле она срабатывает каждый раз на изменение букв и потом ещё много раз перевыполняется после того, как слово было быстро напечатано. Что не так?

Comment: Советую присвоить `$('#search_suggestion_holder')` переменной в самом начале кода и переписать код с ее использованием. "говнистость" заметно уменьшится :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `setTimeout` уже был вызван, но ещё не выстрелил — не вызывайте его. Ну и `keyword` получайте опять внутри функции, поданной в `setTimeout`.

```
var timeout = null;
$('#searchword').bind('textchange', function (event, numberkey) {

  var keyword = $(this).val();
  if (keyword.length > 3 && timeout == null) {
    $('#loader').show();
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      timeout = null;
      var keyword1 = $('#searchword').val();
      ...
      $.ajax({
        url:'auto-complete.php',
        data:'keyword='+keyword1,
        ...
```

Comment: блин че-то совсем не-че не понятно, откуда и зачем взялось keyword1? можно ли поподробней расписать ответ

Comment: `keyword1` - локальная переменная внутри анонимной функции поданной в `setTimeout` и отражающая значение `$('#searchword').val()` в момент выстреливания `setTimeout`. Если печатают быстро, `keyword` и `keyword1` могут быть разными.

Comment: можно пожалуйста полностью увидеть пример, а то что то все ровно не могу понять, есть ли там просто `keyword` или остался только `keyword1`

Comment: Простите, не буду копировать весь Ваш код. Давайте напряжемся. Переменная `keyword` содержит текст из `'#searchword'` в момент выполнения обработчика события `textchange` (это не стандартное событие jQuery, Вы используете какой-то plugin?). Переменная `keyword1` содержит текст из `'#searchword'` в момент выполнения обработчика события `timeout`. Эти два значения могут быть разными. Что именно Вам непонятно?

Comment: вы правильно поняли, есть плагин, так как стандартными средствами jquery нельзя отследить изменение `input` на прямую а только по `blur`, плагин это решает, А не понятно мне почему сначала в переменную идет функция  `timeout = setTimeout(function() {` а затем аннулирует ее `timeout = null;`

Comment: Очень хорошо. Переменная `timeout` используется как флаг, показывающий находится ли код в состоянии ожидания обработчика `setTimeout` или нет.

Comment: все понятно, спасибо

Comment: один нюанс, теперь во время ожидания он с начало выводит  `var nafin = '<li class="hover-img">Нечего не найдено</li>'` как сделать что бы он не делал срабатывание на это? а только если действительно не найдено? То-есть он пока проходит `1500мс` он успевает с начало вывести то что нечего не найдено а затем уже выводит результат.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31111/discussion-between---and-igor).

Comment: `так как стандартными средствами jquery нельзя отследить изменение input на прямую а только по blur` - keypress, keyup, keydown уже отменили?